# Python Webdriver Unable to locate the xpath in button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Using Selenium in Python, trying to write something and click a button.
I've tried `find_element_by_class_name`, `id`, and lastly trying `xpath`.
but can't get it work, can anyone share ideas on how to enable this code?
or any good tutorial resource to pick up basic html/css knowledge using ?

Comment: Can you try by calling `driver.switch_to_alert()` before.

Comment: Can you Show me the `inspect` details of that button ? By right clicking on **Publish**

Comment: It might be a separate frame also

Comment: Any such automation is against Facebook’s ToS, and I have not seen anyone so far to trying do stuff like this for non-shady purposes ... If you want to automate publishing posts to your page or sth. like that - you should use their API.

Comment: @SunilT : like driver.switch_to_alert("class name")?

Comment: @ksai : please find uploaded photo in the post

Comment: @santhoshkumar thanks i will try to do more study

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the advice, I am new to developing world and wasn't aware of ToS policy, will take it down and take a look at FB's api Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
by_css = find_element_by_css_selector("#js_18 > div._1j2v > div._2dck._4-u3._57d8 > div > div._ohf.rfloat > div > button > span")
by_xpath = find_element_by_xpath ("//*[@id="js_18"]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/button/span")
```